How can I find these files and remove them?
I’ve been trying to clean up the “Allow in the Background” section on my Mac, where I found many items from uninstalled apps still listed. I managed to remove most of them after searching through various posts, but there was one stubborn item—ClarityApp—that I couldn’t get rid of.

Despite looking everywhere on my Mac, I couldn’t locate the related files. Then, I came across this post and tried the suggested command. It worked, and I was finally able to view the information related to ClarityApp.

However, I’m puzzled by what the developer did. The files shown in the “URL” section seem to point to locations that don’t exist on my system, and I still can’t find any trace of them.
Has anyone else encountered this issue or knows how to resolve it? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

That suggests that you launched this app from a DMG disk image. It maybe that the database of Allowed apps still contains this entry, even though the app is no longer available. It's untidy, but not a problem.

But I want it to be tidy :(
I've found someone's solution, posted in the answer.

Found this solution which works perfectly as I wished:

Problem
After uninstalling an app the app may still show under:
System Settings -> General -> Login Items -> Allow in the Background
Solution
Follow these step to remove the background item:

Note down the enabled/disabled state of all existing background items. We will need to reset these states later.
Optional: Run sudo sfltool dumpbtm to list all background item info and check that the one to remove is listed.
Run sudo sfltool resetbtm to reset login and background item data. This also enables all background items.
Restart the computer. The leftover background item should now be gone.
Reset remaining background items back to their original enabled/disabled state.

Reference Manage login items and background tasks on Mac | Apple
Platform
Deployment

